# Cpu fans spins and stops repeatedly without any display in monitor

Tags: cpu

Today i was using my computer when the voltage was low and i didn't khew that and my computer suddenly switched off and when i tried to turn it on again it was not was not starting.now my cpu fans spins and stops repeatedly without any display in the monitor and even sometimes cpu gives no any response. I tried cleaning the ram but it gives no response.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If your computer is not posting at all it is a hardware fault. Begin removing components until it posts again, or take it a competent local PC tech for diagnosis.